# rails asset-url from javascript css

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, helper

I have an external javascript plugin and there is a lot of code like this where the image src attribute is built dynamically.

```
$prod.append("<img class='fx_shadow' id='shd_" + i + "' + src='" + folderAssets + "/shadow_fx.png' />");
```

With rails 4.1+, I am precompiling the related images and assets that this external code provides and references above. Naturally, the images fail to load in production because using direct src attributes doesn't capture the fingerprint of the digested and precompiled image.

How do I call the `asset_url` method (which does output the correct asset file name with the digest) properly from an external **javascript** file rather than a **css** file? (This javascript is not a restful template js.erb file, but rather, a js file included in the manifest.)

Also, is there an elegant way to approach and refactor this?

Comment: What's the file's extension you have for your JavaScript is it .js or .js.erb?

Comment: js. I should change it to use js.erb?

Comment: Yes, change it to `.js.erb` and then: `$prod.append("<img class='fx_shadow' id='shd_" + i + "' + src='<%= asset_path('shadow_fx.png') %>' />");`

Comment: I am not if this will work, but also try doing this: `$prod.append("<%= image_tag 'shadow_fx.png', :class => 'fx_shadow' %>");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [**2.3.3 JavaScript/CoffeeScript and ERB**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets). You need to change `.js` to `.js.erb` extension, for example: **javascript_filename.js.erb**. Then you can use it like so:

```
$prod.append("<img class='fx_shadow' id='shd_" + i + "' + src='<%= asset_path('shadow_fx.png') %>' />");
```

or:

```
var image = $("<%= image_tag 'shadow_fx.png', :class => 'fx_shadow' %>");
image.attr('id', 'shd_'+i);
$prod.append(image);
```

In second option, you have to make `image_tag` as image element and then add `id` attribute to it because `i` is a JavaScript variable, that's why it has to be added in a separate line.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1

Add a function

```
function imagePath(image){
    return "http://" + window.location.host + "/assets/"+ image;
}

$prod.append("<img class='fx_shadow' id='shd_" + i + "' + src=imagePath(image) />");
```

## Solution 2

Change the file from `js` to `js.erb`

```
$prod.append("<img class='fx_shadow' id='shd_" + i + "' + src='<%= asset_path('shadow_fx.png') %>' />");
```